# How to merge features branches to branch develop in Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I am new to Git and I have a simple question

Though this has been asked many times in this forum, I want to restrict my question to the following scenario

```
1)  Feature A  (Files A, B and C were modified) cut from 'develop'
2)  Feature B  (Files A and D were modified) cut from 'develop'
```

Feature A has been merged into branch 'develop' successfully

Now the question is, what approach should we follow to merge 'Feature B' to branch 'develop'

Should we pull the latest version of 'develop' and merge the changes of 'feature b' (or)
What other best approaches to merge 'feature b' to 'develop' so that 'File A' has all the changes?

Comment: A sync or pull should be done first and then go ahead with merging Feature B.

Comment: My personal preference is to rebase B back to current develop then merge. But that's only my preference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are alone working on `FeatureB` branch, the a `pull --rebase develop` is the best practice: you are replaying `FeatureB` changes on top of `FeatureA`. (and `git push --force` after).

If you are multiple developers working on `FeatureB`, then a merge of `develop` to `FeatureB` has to be done, before merging `FeatureB` to develop.

In both cases, the idea is the same: test the integration of both features locally (pull or rebase), before merging back to `develop`.

Do not merge to `develop` first, "hoping" that the result (on `develop`) is "good enough".

Answer (score 17):

Let us say that you are not going to have conflicts among your merges/rebases and you work locally (no fetches/pulls/pushes) for the sake of simplicity.

There are basically two ways to proceed. Merging or rebasing. Both get the same result. You decide depending on your work policy.

You can merge:

```
                     //      C3-C4
git checkout develop //     /     \
git merge featureB   // C1-C2--C5--C6
```

Or you can rebase:

```
                       //      C3-C4
git checkout featureB  //     /
git rebase develop     // C1-C2--C5--C3'--C4'
```

The code in the commit `C6` and `C4'` is the same.

If you use the policy of "merging" you can see with a GUI (e.g. gitk) the different features that you were doing quickly.

If you use the policy of "rebasing" you can follow easier the evolution of your proyect when you use commands like `git log`